# How to use a controller for generate URLs SEO all links

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, clean-urls

I have a table with which I want to make a catalog.

My table is like this:

```
Id Product Description Price
```

I'm going to make an index where I list all the products with their name and they link me with a link to a view where I have their description, I know how to do all that, but I do not know how to make each link of the index automatically or generically received the driver for example:

```
<a href="https://example.tld/product/id/name-of-product">name of product</a>
```

I do not think I have to create a controller name-of-product and another other-name-of-product I imagine that there is something generic where I send the *controller* **product** *accion* **index**

example: **ProductController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MySite.Controllers
    {
        public class ProductyController: Controller
        {
            // GET: Product
            public ActionResult Index (int id, string productstring)
            {
                return Content (productstring + "example fooo bar ..");
                // or
                return View ("my_generic_view_styled_css.cshtml");
            }
        }
    }
```

so that when you put https://example.tld/product/id/foo-bar-any

I returned my **index.cshtml** with my info I know how to fill it but what I do not know how to do with the urls for SEO

My problem is not to create the index with the links, the problem is that by clicking or going to the url directly there is no error 404

Comment: So why not create a viewmodel in the `Index` function that contains all the links and descriptions, and a view that creates the html ?  You know, like any other normal view/viewmodel.

Comment: My problem is not to create the index with the links, the problem is that by clicking or going to the url directly there is no error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution was the following in case someone serves you

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Producty", 
        url: "producty/{id}/{company}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Producty", action = "Index", id = "", producty = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Other trick is call

```
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //super important for solution
```

Just after of

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

In **RouteConfig.cs**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a routing issue.

How does this seem:

```
[HttpGet("/link/{product}/{id}/{something}")]
public void Link(string product, string id, string something)
{

}
```

This will decode the parts of the url into the separate parts you require.